# Selecting a past time, and past date MySQL - with an if

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

What's a good way of selecting a past date and past time in MySql?

I effectively want to create this -

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS
WHERE DepartureDate < CURDATE()

IF DepartureDate == CURDATE()
THEN DepartureTime must be < CURTIME()
```

Is this something MySQL supports?
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Use `OR` and `AND`, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing dates and times in one field, rather than two.  You can do what you want as:

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOKINGS
WHERE DepartureDate < CURDATE() OR
      DepartureDate = CURDATE() and DepartureTime < TIME(NOW());
```

Comment: Yeah, I've realised now that's it's not exactly ideal. Thanks for the help, and have a nice day/night :)